# Azure API Management : validate jwt token scope

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-api-management

We want to protect API operation call with the validate-jwt policy but I have an issue when I use the required-claims to check the scopes.
Example : I have a token with a scope including several values like "xxx.READ xxx.WRITE yyy.READ yyy.WRITE ..."
For a specific operation I want to use the validate-jwt policy to check if the token contains the scope linked like :

```
    <required-claims>
            <claim name="scp" match="any">
                <value>xxx.READ</value>
            </claim>
    </required-claims>
```

But the validation always fails because of the multiple values in the scp... How can I check this claim? Do I have to extract the scp values before and if yes how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Multi-value claims should be represented as arrays inside JWT token:

```
"scp": ["xxx.READ", "xxx.WRITE", "yyy.READ", "yyy.WRITE"]
```

this scenarios is completely supported with policy configuration that you've posted.

But if you represent them as a single string ("xxx.READ xxx.WRITE yyy.READ yyy.WRITE") then you have to use manual expressions to validate such token, something along these lines:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))">
        <set-variable name="token" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", string.Empty).AsJwt())" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@{
if (context.Variables["token"] == null) {
    return false;
}

var scp = ((Jwt)context.Variables["token"]).Claims.GetValueOrDefault("scp", (string[])null);
if (scp == null || scp.Length == 0) {
    return false;
}

return scp.Any(c => c.Contains("xxx.READ"));
            }">
                <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
                    <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
            <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
        </return-response>
    </otherwise>
</choose>
```

Comment: Ok. It's Azure AD B2C from Microsoft that generate the scp with the format I explained "xxx.READ yyy.READ ..."

Comment: Oh, that's not nice. I'll look into that, thanks for reporting.

Comment: It will be great. We plan to work with the new "published scopes" & "api access" options on Azure AD B2C even if, for now, we still don't have a page, linked to the scopes targeted, for asking the consent of user. I tried to use your example but it failed with an error on the condition. Thx

Comment: While I look into how we could handle multivalued claims, what error did you receive from condition?

Comment: Hello thanks for your support : the trace --> choose (130 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
            "expression": "!((Jwt)context.Variables[\"token\"]).Claims[\"scp\"].Any(c => c.Contains(\"randomscope.WRITE\"))",
            "details": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        },
        "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    ]
}

Comment: hello any news on this topic @Vitaliy Kurokhtin ?

Comment: Seems like we'll need to change policy to support this scenario as it is unlikely that B2C will change claim representation. Meanwhile let's try to resolve this null ref, I've updated policy in the answer, give it a try.

Comment: ok just found why it was bugging : it is a bearer token so I need to split the string and only use the second values. but for us it will be more clean to be able to check the values thanks to the validate-jwt

Answer (score 3):

I'm also setting up API Management with B2C and I have exactly the same problem.
The solution that i'm using is easier.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="The Scope claim does not contain the read permission." require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true" clock-skew="0">
            <openid-config url="{{your-openid-config-url}}" />
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="scp" match="any" separator=" ">
                    <value>read</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 1):

To validate that a scope is present within the JWT, use the `separator` attribute set to "," since this is a multi-value claim like this: **"scope": ["api1.write","roles","profile"]** .

For example:

```
<required-claims>
   <claim name="scope" match="all" separator=",">
        <value>api1.write</value>
   </claim>
</required-claims>
```

Comment: Is scope not 'scp'?